# Why doesn't a string get replaced when using the Replace method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Completed";
            string tables = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tblProducts").InnerText;
            var lines = tables.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
            string line1 = lines[0];
            string newline1 = line1.Insert(54, ", ").Insert(36, ", ").Insert(32, ", ").Insert(23, ", ").Insert(12, ", ").Insert(4, ", ");
            lines[0].Replace(line1, newline1);
            lines.Insert(1, "");
            string newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\table\Table" + count.ToString("D6") + ".txt");
            w.WriteLine(newText);
            w.Close();
            complete = true;
            count ++;
        }
```

line1 conteint is: תאורסוג פריטמספר קטלוגיתוצר הרכבמצאיתוקף וחלות האחריותמחיר לצרכן
Then i inserted spaces in newline1: תאור, סוג פריט, מספר קטלוגי, תוצר הרכב, מצאי, תוקף וחלות האחריות, מחיר לצרכן

But in the end in newText i see the old line. line1 and not newline1.
Tried lines[0].Replace(line1, newline1); and also lines[0].Replace(newline1, line1); but still i see the old line all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any string manipulation, you have to assign the new value back to the original:

```
lines[0] = lines[0].Replace(line1, newline1);
```

In this case though, since you're replacing the *entire* line, you can just do this:

```
lines[0] = newline1;
```